# Make a single HTTP request from multiple invocations

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm calling a batch request that invokes the callback for *each* item returned.

```
const getBalances = async (addresses, callback) => {
  const decimals = await contract.methods.decimals().call();
  const batch = new web3.BatchRequest();
  for (let address of addresses)
    batch.add(
      contract.methods
        .balanceOf(address)
        .call.request(
          { from: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" },
          (err, balance) => {
            if (err) callback(err);
            balance = balance / 10 ** decimals;
            callback(undefined, balance);
          }
        )
    );
  batch.execute();
};
```

Each item that's returned by the batch request invokes the below callback, so this callback gets invoked once for `address1` and once for `address2`.

```
getBalances([address1, address2], async (err, balance) => {
   if (err) throw new Error()
   if (balance < 100) return
   const price = await getPrice() // getPrice() triggers a GET request
   // use price to do additional processing
}
```

If either callback returns balance >= 100, I need to make a GET request to do more processing, but this request can't be made preemptively because both callbacks may return a balance of < 100, in which case `getPrice()` wouldn't be needed.

```
const getPrice = () => {
   const { price } = await axios.get(url)
   return price
}
```

If both callbacks returned a balance of > 100, then calling `getPrice()` would make one redundant request. What is the proper way of calling an asynchronous function (`getPrice()`) *once* for multiple invocations, so the first invocation would make an HTTP request, and all other invocations would be notified of the single request response?

Comment: I don't understand the structure of the problem.  Can `getPrice()` request multiple price values in one GET request?  Or, are do you just need a cache to prevent requesting prices that you've recently already requested?

Comment: Exactly the latter, where each callback's invocation can be notified by a single response.

Comment: Also, what gets called multiple times?  The callback?  What is calling it and why?  You don't show what you're really trying to accomplish here so the question is pretty abstract and that's maybe why it's hard to understand.  What is the end goal here?

Comment: Did you tried with promises?

Comment: If you're going to implement a cache, it would probably be inside of `getPrice()` so we'd want to see that code.

Comment: @SasiRekha - This already uses promises for `getPrice()` and for `callback()`.

Comment: So you can use Promise.all and can return all the responses at once

Comment: @jfriend00 see edit. Should I consider passing an array of callbacks to `getPrice()` and calling them each with the response once returned?

Comment: I dont' think I will understand your problem until I see what is actually driving things - what is calling the `callback()`.  It seems like that's where you start with the structural question.  If there's only one price and it's good for some period of time, then just save the last price and the time that you fetched it and if too much time hasn't passed, just return the previously fetched price.  That's a simple one item cache.

Comment: FYI, your `getPrice()` can just be `return axios.get(url)`.  There's no need for `response = await axios.get()` and then just `return response`.

Comment: Since you know you're going to eventually need to get the price, why not just get it once at a higher level and pass it along to the functions that eventually need it.

Comment: Because I need to check that at least one of the returned balances is > 100 first, or I risk calling it unnecessarily. It needs to be called at that point, because calling it preemptively would give me a stale price.

Comment: Then, cache the price somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant: [How to have multiple requests for the same data all use the same request/result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259371/how-to-hold-a-nodejs-application-until-other-promise-completes/34259604#34259604).

Comment: You have to cache the promise, not the value.  Something else related here: [How to cache token that has to be refreshed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60731854/how-do-i-manage-access-token-in-nodejs-application/60732068#60732068).

Comment: The first link is exactly what the doctor ordered. Perfect solution. Thank you. Happy to mark accepted if you post as an answer.

Comment: If I understand clearly, what you need is that "at a given time, only one instance of getPrice is being executed & other callbacks receive the result of this one execution", correct?

Comment: "so the first invocation would make an HTTP request, and all other invocations would be notified of the single request response", are you sure that the api/backend will return same response for multiple http requests? 
I mean it might be possible for 1 api call to return a price of 50 & a second API call to return price of 100 if there is some processing invovled at the backend.

Comment: Yes, the HTTP request is to another API that returns the same value for all requests in a given window. I've already accepted @jfriend00's first link above to already work, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the promise returned from `getPrice()` and have every request that calls it within a certain time window just all get the same promise.  This will handle the case where the 2nd call to `getPrice()` comes in before the first one has finished.  The 2nd one will just get the promise that the first one is already waiting on and thus they will all share the same result and will issue only one request.

There's an implementation of this here: [How to have multiple requests for the same data share the same result and request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259371/how-to-hold-a-nodejs-application-until-other-promise-completes/34259604#34259604).